# Difference between "make geth" and "make all" in geth when building from source

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

In geth, when I run the command "make geth", I'm then able to run geth successfully.

But, in the Readme, it suggests to run "make all" immediately afterwards.

I was wondering what "make all" does, since "make geth" appears to create a functional version of geth by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geth github repository comes with a bunch of other command-line tools, such as puppeth and bootnode. These are used to help developers create new genesis blocks or test networks for developing in coordination with the ethereum test network.

"make geth" builds only the single command line client.

"make all" will build all of these helper tools.